Incremental Copy using Power Automate Cloud Flow/Azure Logic App
I am currently trying to move data incrementally from SharePoint Online Folder to Azure BLOB storage. I have been able to set the configuration using Azure Logic App.
There is an event-based trigger when a file is created in a SharePoint folder which starts the entire flow and moves to the Blob storage. The works fine.
But for subsequent flows such as incremental if the files will be uploaded daily, I have tried configuring to get the metadata for the SharePoint folder for the LastModified date. But it doesn't have that much functionality as ADF when performing incremental copy.
I will appreciate any guidence on how to acheive this without needing to use ADF as it will require a lot of configuration to use on SharePoint folder and doesn't give me the necessary flexibility.
I have also attached an image of what have been done so far, which does a full copy all the time.
Thanks

I have tried configuring to get the metadata for the SharePoint folder for the LastModified date. But it doesn't have as much functionality as ADF when performing incremental copy.

Sorry but not sure what the issue is, define “incremental”. I ask because if your trigger is the change trigger then that technically is incremental.

I do agree with @skin, but if you want to know if a blob exists or not and then create that blob you can use below design:
You can use parallel action to copy all blobs at first:

then:

then:

then:

Output:



Can you clarify what exactly you are achieving by listing all blobs (let's say there are 1,000 of them) and then for each of those 1,000 blobs where the filename is different to a filename in the trigger you're creating a blob with the details from the SharePoint trigger (same blob created 999 or 1,000 times)? Am I misreading something?

I am creating a blob when a new file comes in sharepoint , condition is If a file does not exist in Storage account only then I am then i am creating a  new blob.

But this happens inside the For each loop - so you are creating same file multiple times. Your condition is not "a file does not exist" - your condition is "the name of the blob inside the For each loop is not the same as the name of the SharePoint file". You can test it by having lots of blobs in your blob storage and running your workflow then.

Currently, you are using the When a file is created in a folder (deprecated) trigger. This trigger fires when a file is created in a SharePoint folder, but not when the file is updated.
If I understood your question correctly, you want to copy data from SharePoint to a blob storage incrementally, that is if a file with the same name but a different content is uploaded to SharePoint daily, your workflow should notice it and copy the file to the blob storage.
You can achieve this by using a different trigger - When a file is created or modified in a folder (deprecated).
Your workflow would look as follows:

Trigger When a file is created or modified in a folder (deprecated)
Action Create blob (V2)

There's no need to use the For each loop. You might need to use a loop in another process to copy all SharePoint files to the blob storage initially, before this "incremental copy" workflow starts operating.
